# Can the future tense be translated as present in Romans 6:5?

Tags: greek, romans, translation-philosophy

Romans 6:5 says we shall be in the future tense.

> For if we have been planted together in the likeness of His death, so we shall also be in the likeness of His resurrection. KJV

Could it be translated in the present tense to say we are also in the likeness of his resurrection?

> For if we have been planted together in the likeness of His death,  we are also in the likeness of His resurrection.

In other words, can the future tense sometimes be translated as present in Greek?

Comment: It is not clear what the second quotation is : is it your own 'translation' ? The verbs are present and then future. Are you trying to force them both to be present ? And if so, what evidence do you have ? This question needs further clarity and further detail, please. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, left) as to the purpose and the functioning of this, an hermeneutical site.

Comment: You will need to explain the origin of the second translation above.

Comment: Hi Esteban, Welcome to the site! Questions that are marked as unclear can be voted upon for closure by the community but you do have an opportunity to edit if you wish.  I can post an example to help you get the hang of it, but again, it will depend on what others think because this is a community based site.

Comment: If the suggested edit does not capture your intent, you can edit it yourself. Sometimes it helps to explain what your reasons are behind asking a question to help people understand where you are coming from and give better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

King James Bible Romans 6:5

> For if we have been planted together in the likeness of his death, we shall be also in the likeness of his resurrection:

OP: Romans 6:5 says we shall be in the past tense

This English is not past tense. It's future tense.

Romans 6:5 says we shall be in the past tense, could it say we are also in the likeness of his resurrection?

Let's see the Greek,
https://biblehub.com/romans/6-5.htm:

we will certainly also be
ἐσόμεθα (esometha)
Verb - **Future** Indicative Middle - 1st Person Plural

The original Greek verb is in the future tense.

Could it say we are also in the likeness of his resurrection?

No. You have the present tense. The Greek is in the future tense.

Answer (score 0):

These verses in Romans 6 state our death with Christ as an accomplished fact and our resurrection with Christ as what should be the result of that death.

That might lead some to speculate that our death with Christ to sin has already been accomplished, while our resurrection with Him (in context, spiritual resurrection) has *yet* to be accomplished. Yet comparison with other scripture will reveal that is *not* so.

Ephesians 2:5-6 states our spiritual resurrection with Christ as an accomplished fact that happens at salvation. Colossians 2:12-13 makes the same claim. In Colossians 3:1, Paul used the reasoning that if we are risen with Christ, then we should seek those things that are above. Just as surely as all Christians are to seek heavenly things, likewise, all Christians have been raised with Christ.

Comment: The fact that Paul uses, “we should” speaks to this state being figurative and a preliminary phase before the true raising at Jesus’ return. We are, but not yet. As he is raised to immortality, so we are yet to be. We are not fully raised, only ‘gifted’ the spirit of new life.

Comment: @steveowen It depends on how you view ‘who’ you are. I emphasised the context of these verses is man’s ‘spirit’. So, I somewhat agree - We (our body) will not be raised (recreated immortal) until our resurrection.

Comment: I think you're mistaken to assert that Paul is talking about a spiritual resurrection. Paul, knew what he was doing with the future tense. If we agree that the spiritual resurrection has already occurred then he couldn't be talking about that one, but the future resurrection that remains of the body. No need to assume Paul got his tenses wrong.